# How to apply an user interface orientation to an iOS storyboard scene

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode-storyboard

I am developing an iOS application that allows someone to play one of two different games.

Both games are played in a set of rounds. When a player finishes a round the application transitions to a new scene that displays results and then either transitions to another round scene or an end game scene.

Because of the transient nature of the scenes in the application, it makes little sense to persist scenes  as is done in more traditional applications, where someone can return to a previous scene.

To that end, most scene navigation is accomplished by using a `UINavigationViewController` and simply calling `setViewControllers(animated:)` supplying an array that contains only the `UIViewController` for the next scene, and this works quite well.

I mentioned that the application will allow someone to play one of two games. It turns out that, on the iPhone, one game is best played in portrait mode, and the other game works best played in landscape mode. I want to be able to control what user interface orientation is used for a particular `UIViewController` when it becomes active.

I have experimented with using the `supportedInterfaceOrientations` property of the `UINavigationController` and `application(_ application: supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window:)` for `UIApplicationDelegate`, and have been able to get things to work for a standard application. However, when I try to apply things to the way my game application works using `setViewControllers(animated:)`, no methods that pertain to applying the desired user interface orientation seem to get called, and all scenes appear at the same orientation.

What suggestions do people have for how I could get a scene in my application to appear with a particular user interface orientation?

Answer (score 0):

Try making your presented view controller call the following method on it's view will appear, or view did appear:

```
class func attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()
```

> Some view controllers may want to use app-specific conditions to
>   determine what interface orientations are supported. If your view
>   controller does this, when those conditions change, your app should
>   call this class method. The system immediately attempts to rotate to
>   the new orientation.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621400-attemptrotationtodeviceorientati

Comment: This is interesting. I added a call to UIViewController. attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation in the viewDidAppear method for each view controller. It turns out that the supportedInterfaceOrientations property for each view controller is access when this happens. Each view controller that needs a special orientation returns the desired orientation, however there appears to be no effect. The views still all show up in the same orientation.

Comment: The supportedInterfaceOrientations property only gets access if the UINavigationController is changed from just using setViewControllers(,animated: true) to calling setViewControllers(,animated: true) with an empty UIViewController array to clear everything out and then calling pushViewController(, animated: true). This doesn’t animate very well, and using it doesn’t ultimately solve the problem anyway